# Cannot add or update a child row but foreign key exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have these two tables on my database:

[image]

[image]

And this is part of my code:
Here is where I store the new complaint

```
public function storeComplaint($data)
{
    $complaint = new Complaint;
    $complaint->complainttype_id = $data->complainttype;
    $complaint->restaurant_id = $data->restaurant;
    $complaint->user_id = $data->vendor;
    $complaint->date = $data->date;
    $complaint->comments = $data->comments;
    $complaint->save();

    $this->storeComplaint_Product($complaint->id, $data->products); //THIS IS TO INSERT INTO THE COMPLAINT_PRODUCTS TABLE

    return $complaint;
}
```

This is where I store into the Complaint_Products table:

```
public function storeComplaint_Product($complaint_id, $products)
{
    Complaint_Product::where('complaint_id', '=', $complaint_id)->delete();

    if(!empty($products))
    {
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            $complaint_product = new Complaint_Product;
            $complaint_product->complaint_id = $complaint_id;
            $complaint_product->product_id = $product;
            $complaint_product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I call storeComplaint_Product I send the complaint->id and the products I want to store. still it gets me that "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" when I just created that complaint. It even shows me the information I'm trying to insert and those ids exists!!

[image: Lara]

Comment: maybe "$complaint_product->product_id = $product;" must be `$complaint_product->product_id = $product->id;`

Comment: What's in `$data->products` if you do a dd?

Comment: It is an array containing only the ids. Example:
$products = [2,6,3].

Comment: ok, in the error it is not possible to read in which fk the foreign key restriction fails. The part of Complaint looks good, so I assume it's some id of the products. Are you sure that all the ids in the array correspond to the ids of existing products?

Comment: Yes, They all exists, I select the products ids from a select showing all existing products. and in the error example I attached on the post, it shows the information trying to insert into Complaint_Product  8 being the id from the complaint and 2 being the id from the product. Both do exist.

Comment: Can you show me the migration for Complaint_Product ? @RobertSerrano

Comment: I'm really not sure how to show you that. I usually only edit the model and synchronize it with my database.

Comment: That's how I work most of the time. And I have this kind of tables multiple times, so I do not know what's going on this time.